# Unable to make sense of URL for connection reading a svg file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, svg, batik

I have a Spring Boot v2.1.2.RELEASE application.
I have a file in  `../src/main/resources/icons/128/black/ae.png`

which I want to read, But I got an error: **Unable to make sense of URL for connection**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SvgManagerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SvgManagerApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      

        try {

            String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
            SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
            Document doc = f.createDocument("classpath:icons/128/black/ae.svg");

            System.out.println(doc);

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your file is .png not .svg

Comment: Its ok now, copy & paste error

Comment: `classpath:` is a spring resource location and cannot be used else where. Also you wouldn't be able to create anything in the classpath as that is unmodifiable..

Comment: I guess you have a problem on addressing your svg file. to making sure of that for debugging purpose fill the absolute address in `f.createDocument` then you can resolve the problem of addressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two different framework; `classpath:` is related to Spring while `SAXSVGDocumentFactory` seems to be related to batik (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/anim/dom/SAXSVGDocumentFactory.html)

You can do in this way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SvgManagerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SvgManagerApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      

        try {
        Resource svg = new ClassPathResource("icons/128/black/ae.png"); 
            String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
            SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
            Document doc = f.createDocument(SVG_DOCUMENT_URI, svg.getInputStream());

            System.out.println(doc);

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

More information about Resource can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html, while more information about ClassPathResource can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html

Comment: well this depends on your SVG file. You should give a look to batik examples http://people.apache.org/~clay/batik/domapi.html#Creating+a+Document+from+an+SVG+file and https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/dom-api.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the path in this way:

```
String path = SvgManagerApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("icons/128/black/ae.svg").getPath();
```